# How to get the value from the react fabric ui checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

This is the **JSX** tag. I'm getting the status of the checkbox but not the value or the label name.

```
<Checkbox label="Innovation" value="Innovation" onChange={this._onChange} />
```

Below is the code that shows the status

```
public _onChange(ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>, isChecked: boolean) {
  console.log(`The option has been changed to ${isChecked}.`);
```

I tried to pass the value but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Checkbox` tag inside `Stack` tag like this

```
<Stack>
  <Checkbox label="Innovation" onChange={_onChange} />
</Stack>

function _onChange(ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>, isChecked: boolean) {
  console.log(`The option has been changed to ${isChecked}.`);
}
```

For more reference you can go through [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Checkbox/examples/Checkbox.Basic.Example.tsx)

Comment: Stack is to align the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the [inputProps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react/icheckboxprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#inputProps) attribute to set the value and id of the element.

After you set the value and id of the element, then in the onChangeEvent, you can read these values from event object

```
<FabricCheckbox ...props inputProps={{value:myVal, id:myId}} onChange={(e, checked) => this.handleOnChange}/>
...
handleOnChange(event, checked) {
    const selectedVal = event.target.value; //This will return the value you set
}
```